# ¿De que manera puedo mostrar un registro según su indice o numero de fila en una sentencia ORDER BY?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, bucle-for

Lo que quiero hacer es, que en mi pagina web, estos divs se muestren **ordenados por su Titulo ascendentemente**. Sin embargo, lo que pasa es que solo muestra el primer registro del ORDER BY y lo repite $numeropeliculas [image: esto es lo que me muestra el codigo.]

Entonces, por eso quiero saber de que manera de mostrar los registros provenientes del resultado de sentencia ORDER BY, por medio de el indice de fila (0,1,2..), y ya con esto nomas reemplazo dicho indice por la variable de mi ciclo. Ya que para mostrar los divs estoy ocupando un ciclo (vease en el codigo)[image: codigo php] O si es que no hay una manera mas simple.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en que la consulta

```
$sentencia = "SELECT * FROM películas ORDER BY Titulo ASC";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$sentencia);
$row =resultado->fetch_array();
```

la estás haciendo dentro del ciclo *for* por este motivo cada vez que entra al ciclo busca en la base de datos todas las películas y te da la primera.
 Entonces debería ser

```
$sentencia = "SELECT * FROM películas ORDER BY Titulo ASC";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$sentencia);
for($i=0; $<=$numeroPeliculas; $i++){
    $row =resultado->fetch_array();
     //...  Todo tú código que utiliza $row
}
```

Incluso te recomiendo investigar *foreach* y te puedes ahorrar la variable $numeroPeliculas, ya que este ciclo recorre todo el arreglo obtenido.

Saludos, espero sea de ayuda